# Adding Dynamic Attr() to d3.tip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Problem:**

I'm trying to add a `data-data` attribute with the first index of the dataset to each of my tooltips as they're generated by the code, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to dynamically set it based on the dataset.

For example, I want to achieve the equivalent of this:

```
const tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('data-date', d => d[0])
    //...
```

Here's a code snippet:

```js
//need to fix tooltip data-date attr.. don't know how I'll do that yet though

const endpoint =
 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";

d3.json(endpoint).then(data => {
 const gc = d3.select(document.getElementById("graph-container")),
  dataset = data.data,
  canvasWidth = 900,
  canvasHeight = 477,
  padding = 50,
  years = dataset.map(s => s[0].slice(0, 4)),
  xScale = d3
   .scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, dataset.length])
   .range([padding, canvasWidth - padding]),
  yScale = d3
   .scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d[1])])
   .range([padding, canvasHeight - padding]),
  tip = d3 //making a tooltip
   .tip()
   .attr("id", "tooltip")
   .direction("e")
   .offset([0, 25])
   .html(
    d =>
     `${d[0].slice(0, 4)} Q${
      d[0].slice(5, 7) === "01"
       ? "1"
       : d[0].slice(5, 7) === "04"
        ? "2"
        : d[0].slice(5, 7) === "07"
         ? "3"
         : d[0].slice(5, 7) === "10" ? "4" : null
     }<br />$${d[1]} Billion`
   ),
  xAxis = d3
   .axisBottom(
    d3
     .scaleLinear()
     .domain([d3.min(years), d3.max(years)])
     .range([padding, canvasWidth - padding])
   )
   .tickFormat(d3.format("d")),
  yAxis = d3.axisLeft(
   d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d[1])])
    .range([canvasHeight - padding, padding])
  ); //not sure how to make this work without redefining the range. point is, however, it works... so... take that

 gc //making the title element
  .append("div")
  .attr("id", "title")
  .text("National Income and Product Accounts of the United States (NIPA)");

 gc //making the graph
  .append("svg")
  .attr("id", "canvas")
  .attr("width", canvasWidth)
  .attr("height", canvasHeight)
  .call(tip)
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .style('fill', (d, i) => d[1] <= dataset[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1][1] ? '#f92727' : '#00cc58')
  .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
  .attr("y", d => canvasHeight - yScale(d[1]))
  .attr("width", canvasWidth / dataset.length)
  .attr("height", d => yScale(d[1]) - padding)
  .attr("data-date", d => d[0])
  .attr("data-gdp", d => d[1])
  .on("mouseover", tip.show)
  .on("mouseout", tip.hide);

 d3 //add x-axis
  .select(document.getElementById("canvas"))
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "x-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${canvasHeight - padding})`)
  .call(xAxis);

 d3 //add y-axis
  .select(document.getElementById("canvas"))
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "y-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${padding}, 0)`)
  .call(yAxis);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');

* {
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Lato';
}

html, body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100vh;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, #ffffe6);
}

#graph-container {
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 1px gray;
 height: 550px;
 width: 950px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: white;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

#title {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 15px;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 gray;
}

#canvas {
 background-color: transparent;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.bar:hover {
 fill: yellow;
}

#tooltip {
 background-color: orange;
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 min-width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <div id="graph-container"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried attaching the dataset to the `tip` variable and pass it through on `.attr` but unfortunately the dataset only can be passed through the `.html` without breaking.

I've tried moving the `.call` for tip to have the data passed through, but that isn't working either.

I have to use `.attr` and can't fake it in the html by attaching the attribute to a generated div/span/etc.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: have you ever examined what all the arguments are to your `html()` call? Why do you need different scales to draw the axes, have a closer look at how you select items by ID, why do you keep fiddling with the `padding` variable,......  Have you considered writing a `mouseover` callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3-tip` is a pretty self-contained entity, so if you want to do this, you're basically going to have to hack it; there isn't a nice way to do it through the official API. During the `html` function, you can manipulate the `tip` DOM element and add an attribute to it using the current data item:

```
            .html(
                d => {
                // slightly horrible hack
                d3.select('#tooltip').attr('data-date', d[0]);
                    return `${d[0].slice(0, 4)} Q${
                        d[0].slice(5, 7) === "01"
                            ? "1"
                            : d[0].slice(5, 7) === "04"
                                ? "2"
                                : d[0].slice(5, 7) === "07"
                                    ? "3"
                                    : d[0].slice(5, 7) === "10" ? "4" : null
                    }<br />$${d[1]} Billion`
            }),
```

Integrated into the whole code:

```js
//need to fix tooltip data-date attr.. don't know how I'll do that yet though

const endpoint =
 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";

d3.json(endpoint).then(data => {
 const gc = d3.select(document.getElementById("graph-container")),
  dataset = data.data,
  canvasWidth = 900,
  canvasHeight = 477,
  padding = 50,
  years = dataset.map(s => s[0].slice(0, 4)),
  xScale = d3
   .scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, dataset.length])
   .range([padding, canvasWidth - padding]),
  yScale = d3
   .scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d[1])])
   .range([padding, canvasHeight - padding]),
  tip = d3 //making a tooltip
   .tip()
   .attr("id", "tooltip")
   .direction("e")
   .offset([0, 25])
   .html(
    d => {
                d3.select('#tooltip').attr('data-date', d[0]);
     return `${d[0].slice(0, 4)} Q${
      d[0].slice(5, 7) === "01"
       ? "1"
       : d[0].slice(5, 7) === "04"
        ? "2"
        : d[0].slice(5, 7) === "07"
         ? "3"
         : d[0].slice(5, 7) === "10" ? "4" : null
     }<br />$${d[1]} Billion`
   }),
  xAxis = d3
   .axisBottom(
    d3
     .scaleLinear()
     .domain([d3.min(years), d3.max(years)])
     .range([padding, canvasWidth - padding])
   )
   .tickFormat(d3.format("d")),
  yAxis = d3.axisLeft(
   d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d[1])])
    .range([canvasHeight - padding, padding])
  ); //not sure how to make this work without redefining the range. point is, however, it works... so... take that

 gc //making the title element
  .append("div")
  .attr("id", "title")
  .text("National Income and Product Accounts of the United States (NIPA)");

 gc //making the graph
  .append("svg")
  .attr("id", "canvas")
  .attr("width", canvasWidth)
  .attr("height", canvasHeight)
  .call(tip)
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .style('fill', (d, i) => d[1] <= dataset[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1][1] ? '#f92727' : '#00cc58')
  .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
  .attr("y", d => canvasHeight - yScale(d[1]))
  .attr("width", canvasWidth / dataset.length)
  .attr("height", d => yScale(d[1]) - padding)
  .attr("data-date", d => d[0])
  .attr("data-gdp", d => d[1])
  .on("mouseover", tip.show)
  .on("mouseout", tip.hide);

 d3 //add x-axis
  .select(document.getElementById("canvas"))
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "x-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${canvasHeight - padding})`)
  .call(xAxis);

 d3 //add y-axis
  .select(document.getElementById("canvas"))
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "y-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${padding}, 0)`)
  .call(yAxis);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');

* {
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Lato';
}

html, body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100vh;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, #ffffe6);
}

#graph-container {
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 1px gray;
 height: 550px;
 width: 950px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: white;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

#title {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 15px;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 gray;
}

#canvas {
 background-color: transparent;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.bar:hover {
 fill: yellow;
}

#tooltip {
 background-color: orange;
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 min-width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <div id="graph-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whatever works works and this worked like a charm. Thanks!